# Semi-simple Banach algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras, amenability

Is there an example of an unital commutative semi-simple Banach algebra which it is not amenable?

Comment: For improving one's stock of examples of Banach algebras, so that one is better placed to answer such questions on one's own, I recommend reading some of the standard textbooks on (commutative) Banach algebras: Rickart; or Bonsall and Duncan; or the recent book of Kaniuth. The last of these has plenty of examples of the kind mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some examples off the top of my head:

1) the disc algebra
$$ A({\mathbb D}) = \{ f \in C(\overline{\mathbb D}) \mid \hbox{$f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{D}$} \} $$
equipped with the supremum norm.

2) $C^1{([0,1])}$, the space of continuously differentiable functions $[0,1]\to {\mathbb C}$ equipped with the norm
$$ \Vert f\Vert_{(1)} = \Vert f\Vert_\infty + \Vert f'\Vert_{\infty} $$

3) $A(SO(3))$, the Fourier algebra of the (real, compact) Lie group $SO(3)$.

All of these examples are semisimple, commutative and unital. Examples 2) and 3) are *regular* Banach algebras; Example 1) is not regular. Examples 1) and 2) have non-zero continuous point-derivations, so are not weakly amenable, hence are not amenable. Example 3) has no non-zero continuous point derivations, but Johnson showed in 1994 that it is not weakly amenable (and hence not amenable).